# Angular 2: Providing Service Implementation based on routes

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-services

I have an angular app `animals`, which displays a picture of an animal depending on the current route location. For example, `/dog` will display dog picture and `/cat` will display the cat picture on the page.

To accomplish it, I have created 3 feature modules - `AnimalBoxModule`, `CatModule` and `DogModule`. `AnimalBoxModule` has a component `AnimalBoxComponent` and a service `AnimalService`. `AnimalBoxComponent` uses `AnimalService.getPicture()` to get the image of the animal. `DogModule` and `CatModule` has `DogService` and `CatService` which can be used to provide custom implementation of `AnimalService` to display picture of cat and dog respectively.

I am rendering `<animal-box></animal-box>` in the `AppComponent`. To display the right picture of animal, I have to provide service implementation (`CatService` or `DogService`) depending on the current route location. How is it possible in Angular?

Thanks in Advance

**Edit**

I dont want to make any changes in `AnimalBoxComponent` which is using the service, because I am presenting it as a reusable component. IMO, it would not be a good idea to change it whenever we want to extend this app to have more animal services.

Comment: hmmm... usually it's better to have separate components if they use different services. but I can see how you could want this. Have you tried using the `ActivatedRouteSnapshot`?

Comment: @FussinHussin No, did not know about it. Going to try that. Thanks

Comment: you can check to see if a string matches the activated route, like dog or cat, and inject the service based on that. the hardest part will be figuring out how to conditionally inject a service.

Comment: Thanks @FussinHussin, Conditionally injecting a service, where I am stuck. Any pointers or hints would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, it looks like you can do this using the Angular Injector, there is a post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43450259/angular-2-conditionally-inject-service-in-component) that answers your question.

```
import { Injector } from '@angular/core'  
...
constructor(private injector: Injector){ 

  if(true) {
    this.oneService = <OneService>this.injector.get(OneService);
  } else {
    this.twoService = <TwoService>this.injector.get(TwoService);
  }
}
```

I would read the post as it has more info on the why.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I am sorry for I haven`t explained my problem well. I have added the explanation in the problem statement, why I am not in favour of this solution.

Comment: hmm, okay I understand that. I'm not sure of another way, you might consider starting a bounty