# How to pass a service to constructor with only optional parameters?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I have a Typescript class where all its constructor parameters are optional. How can I pass a service to it, as it acts as a required parameter ?

**Current Situation :**

```
constructor(label ? : String, location ? : any) {...}
```

**Sort of what I am looking for :**

```
constructor(private myService: MyService, label ? : String, location ? : any) {...}
```

Answer (score 0):

> How can I pass a service to it, as it acts as a required parameter

You get an instance of the service using angular injector.

## More

Get `Injector` : https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/4112#issuecomment-153811572

Answer (score 0):

As @basarat mentioned you can use the Angular injector to "`get`" services which was explained here: [Angular 2 conditionally inject service in component](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43450259/5706293) but this is not a suggested pattern as it seems from the comment section.

---

What you are looking for is explained here: https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection#optional-dependencies

> You can tell Angular that the dependency is optional by annotating the constructor argument with `@Optional()`

after annotating the dependency you simply do an if check in the constructor to see whether it's provided or not.