# Angular condition in type provider with AOT

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, decorator, angular2-aot

I have an Angular project which I compile with AOT. I want to be able to register `ClassProvider` that is resolved dynamically according to configuration. Simplified code I use is this:

```
const isMock = Math.random() > 0.5;

@NgModule({
  // ...
  providers: [
    { provide: MyServiceBase, useClass: (isMock) ? MyServiceMock : MyService },
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

The problem is when I compile this with AOT I always get the same service. I would expect to get different service while hitting F5 (because of the `randomness` on the first line). When compiling without AOT it behaves as I expect.

Here is the whole code example on github: https://github.com/vdolek/angular-test/tree/aot-conditioned-provider-problem. It behaves differently with `ng serve` and `ng serve --aot`.

How can I achieve this? I know I could use `FactoryProvider`, but then I would have to duplicate the services dependencies (parameters of the factory function and deps property on the `FactoryProvider`).

Answer (score 12):

To achieve the dynamic nature of your requirement, you need to use [factory providers,](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection#factory-providers) via the `useFactory` attribute.

I've forked your repository, and amended your [app.module.ts](https://github.com/jeanpaulattard/angular-test/blob/aot-conditioned-provider-problem/src/app/app.module.ts) as follows, to work in AOT.

Amend `app.module.ts` as follows

```
export let myServiceFactory = () => {

  const isMock = Math.random() > 0.5;

  return isMock ? new MyServiceMock() : new MyService();
}; 

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule
  ],
  providers: [
    {provide: MyServiceBase, useFactory: myServiceFactory},
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

In the case that your service is dependent on other services, which, most likely it will, you can use the `deps` argument, to pass on the required dependencies.

Let's say that `MyServiceBase` is dependent on two services, `MyService1` and `MyService2`... Your factory function will look as follows :

```
export let myServiceFactory = (service1:MyService1, service2:MyService2) => {

  const isMock = Math.random() > 0.5;

  return isMock ? new MyServiceMock(service1, service2) : new MyService(service1, service2);
};
```

and your providers decleration would look as follows

```
providers: [
    {
       provide: MyServiceBase, 
       useFactory: myServiceFactory,
       deps: [MyService1, MyService2]
    },
]
```

[This guide](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection) contains further detail on the various ways of achieving dependency injection in Angular.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As I mentioned in my question I am familiar with FactoryProviders. But I dislike that I need to list the dependencies three times (in actual service, in factory signature and in `deps` property). I want to avoid this code duplication - that was the purpose of the question. The `deps` property isn't even statically checked while building so then when somebody changes the dependecies of the service he has to know to change the `deps` property.

Comment: I understand, I have to admit, I've missed that last sentence (my mind automatically when to that solution). As far as I am aware, there is no alternative way to achieve what you require.

Comment: Angular 5 reduces the restrictions on the syntax  of things like factory functions when using AOT.

Answer (score 2):

I think as @jeanpaul-a said you don't have any choice other than to use factory. But managing dependencies could be not very clean. But what you could use is the [Injector](https://angular.io/api/core/Injector). I'll go with something like:

```
@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, FormsModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, HelloComponent ],
  providers: [
    Dep1Service,
    Dep2Service,
    { provide: MyServiceBase, useFactory: createService, deps: [Injector] }
  ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }

export function createService(injector: Injector) {
  const isMock = Math.random() > 0.5;
  if (mock) {
    return new MyService1(injector.get(Dep2Service));
  } else {
    return new MyService2(injector.get(Dep1Service));
  }
}
```

What you could also do is to set MyServiceBase as an interface and use [InjectionToken](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection#dependency-injection-tokens).
You will find a working example [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ix3zmq) (not your class name however).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is not 100% percent my desire. But at least it gives build errors every time dependencies change so the person then knows that an update of factory is required.

Comment: Yes i know but you can't use function call with useClass and your expression will be static when compiled with AOT. So if you want some dynamic you need a factory