# Conditionally apply injected service in component

Tags: angular, typescript

I would like to inject conditionally a service depending on `@Input` value

**service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { DateAdapter } from '@angular/material/core';
import {
  MatDateRangeSelectionStrategy,
  DateRange,
} from '@angular/material/datepicker';

@Injectable()
export class FiveDayRangeSelectionStrategy<D>
  implements MatDateRangeSelectionStrategy<D>
{
  constructor(private _dateAdapter: DateAdapter<D>) {}

  selectionFinished(date: D | null): DateRange<D> {
    return this._createFiveDayRange(date);
  }

  createPreview(activeDate: D | null): DateRange<D> {
    return this._createFiveDayRange(activeDate);
  }

  private _createFiveDayRange(date: D | null): DateRange<D> {
    if (date) {
      const start = this._dateAdapter.addCalendarDays(date, -2);
      const end = this._dateAdapter.addCalendarDays(date, 2);
      return new DateRange<D>(start, end);
    }

    return new DateRange<D>(null, null);
  }
}
```

**component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { MAT_DATE_RANGE_SELECTION_STRATEGY } from '@angular/material/datepicker';
import { SelectionStrategy } from './selectionStrategy.service';

/** @title Date range picker with custom a selection strategy */
@Component({
 selector: 'date-range-picker-selection-strategy-example',
 templateUrl: 'date-range-picker-selection-strategy-example.html',
 providers: [
   {
     provide: MAT_DATE_RANGE_SELECTION_STRATEGY,
     useClass: SelectionStrategy,
   },
 ],
})
export class DateRangePickerSelectionStrategyExample {}
@Input() isStrategy:boolean=false // inject service if true *
```

How can I provide service depending on `isStrategy` Input ?

Here's [an example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mj56mq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdate-range-picker-selection-strategy-example.ts,src%2Fapp%2FselectionStrategy.service.ts)

Comment: Hi, not sure I understood. Are you trying to conditionally provide either `SelectionStrategy` or `FiveDayRangeSelectionStrategy` according to the `isStrategy` input?

Comment: I don't see the difference between them, but for me I should provide them both ? I don't know if only providing  `selectionStrategy` will works. And yes I should provide the same behaviour depending on `isStrategy` value. if `false` do not provide service

Comment: Hi, look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43450259/how-to-conditionally-inject-service-into-component